# List comprehension where if condition is first before loop

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would you translate the following condition into a list comprehension?

```
a = list()
if inputs is not None:
   for i in inputs:
      a.append(my_function(i))
else:
   a.append(my_function())
```

I was thinking:

```
a = [my_function(input) for input in inputs else my_function() if inputs is not None]
```

but getting errors.

Note: This was just a pseudo code with pseudo names. Apologies for confusion.

Comment: You are re-defining variable input. Input is a built-in function. That's not causing the error, but you should never do it.

Comment: In your original code, one cannot tell, that `a` is a list. Does `my_function` returns a list?

Comment: You can't replace this with a list comprehension unless `my_function` itself is returning a list.

Comment: Your first loop effectively ignores the return value of all but the last call to `my_function`. It's seems likely that's not what you want.

Comment: Yes, a is a list. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Is `my_function()` equivalent to `my_function(None)`? If so, `a = [my_function(i) for i in ([None] if inputs is None else inputs)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if needs to be outside the list comprehension:

```py
a = [my_function(i) for i in inputs] if inputs is not None else my_function()
```

I changed `input` to `i`, because `input` is a built-in function.

Comment: This makes `a` a list of results from `my_function`,  which isn't what the OP's original code does. (It just repeated *reassigns* `a` to the return value of `my_function`, effectively only saving the return value of the last call.)

Answer (score 0):

The way your function is written, all you really need is:

```
a = my_function(inputs[-1]) if inputs is not None else my_function()
```

Unless `my_function` has side effects.  Then you could use:

```
a = [my_function(i) for i in inputs][-1] if inputs is not None else my_function()
```

Because you keep overwriting a in the loop so only the last call is kept.

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = [my_function()] if inputs is None else [my_function(i) for i in inputs]
```